# Unix Socket without sending (or receiving) queue

Tags: python, c, sockets, unix-socket

I have a sender/receiver pair of codes written in C and Python. The client is producing data and send it over a unix socket to receiver. Receiver is not always listening to the socket, because it should do something with received data.

In my current code all messages sent by sender are waiting in a queue to be received by receiver, but I don't want this behavior. I want the sender know that the receiver is busy now (maybe even by raising an error). So how can I set the queue length of receiver to zero?

Please consider that I don't want the send or receive procedure be blocking.

My receiver and sender parts of codes are these:

Receiver (in Python):

```
self.app_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
self.app_socket.settimeout(0.01)
self.app_socket.bind(APP_SOCKET)

def poll(self, *args):
    try:
        message = self.app_socket.recv(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        return
```

Sender (in C):

```
int openSocket(char *path)
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    int size;

    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(addr.sun_path, path);
    size = strlen(addr.sun_path) + sizeof(addr.sun_family);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, size) < 0)
        return -1;

    return sock;
}

int sendMessage(int sock, unsigned char *message, int length)
{
    int count;

    count = send(sock, message, length, 0);
    if (count < 0)
        return -1;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: I invite you to see how `man 3 select` work, i think it can help you knowing the state of the receiver

Comment: @CollioTV Thanks, I knew about `select` but I think it's a very general answer. By the way I'm reading this.

Comment: `select()` only tells you if some `send()` will work without blocking, having your sent data end up waiting in an OS buffer is a valid (and likely) occurrence after `select()` tells you it is OK to `send()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell on sender side what is going on on the receiver. May be receiver process is not even scheduled now. The only reasonable way is to answer from receiver back to sender, where you can wait some timeout for this answer and decide whether receiver busy or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, if I want to make it easier, it will be enough for me if messages do not wait in a queue, I mean may I open a socket in receiver code that has not any queue? It's OK for me if I lose messages delivered when the receiver is busy.

Comment: In short words - no, you can't. Generally, when you send() some data, you ask kernel to deliver your message to another socket. In exact that moment (suppose you got 1 cpu, for clarity) your receiver proc is not working, it is waiting for scheduling by kernel. Kernel HAVE to store your message somewhere, where your receiver can get it later, when its proc will be scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

You need some way for the receiver to signal its state (read or not) to the sender.
There are several IPC primitives you might use for this purpose.

Or you could make up your own.
For example the receiver could so something along these line:

```
    mkdir("/path/to/my/flag/dir", 0555);  /* ready */
    read();
    rmdir("/path/to/my/flag/dir");       /* busy */
```

and the sender could periodically check for existence of this with something along these lines:

```
    oktogo = (access("/path/to/my/flag/dir", F_OK) == 0);
```